# How can I get the record of the last insert?

Tags: database, 10

Is there a method to be called that will get the ID of the record just inserted?

In my module the first thing done is the insert of some data into a table.

After that I have other things to do in the same submit method of my module that needs the ID of the record that was created, so I can place it into tables that are related.

I've tried

`$reminder_query->execute();

$reminder_id = $reminder_query->id();`

But keep getting an error.

> Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Insert::id() in Drupal\rmdrs\Form\ReminderForm->submitForm()

Comment: you can use `$query->range(0, 1);`, it would help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = \Drupal::database();

$reminder_query = $db->insert('rmdrs_reminders');
$reminder_query->fields ([
  .......
]);

$reminder_query->values([
  .......
]);
$reminder_query->execute();
$reminder_id = $db->lastInsertId(); // Must refer to the connection to get ID immediately after it is inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming $reminder_query is a database query object.
$reminder_query = \Drupal::database()->select('your_table_name', 't')
  ->fields('t')
  ->condition('your_condition_field', $your_condition_value);

// Add the range to limit the result set to one row.
$reminder_query->range(0, 1);

// Execute the query and fetch the result.
$result = $reminder_query->execute()->fetch();

// Check if a result was found.
if ($result) {
  // Access the 'id' field from the result.
  $reminder_id = $result->id;
  // Use $reminder_id as needed.
} else {
  // Handle the case where no result was found.
}
```